# Законность парсинга сайтов

Tags: java, jsoup, веб-скрейпинг

Есть один сайт, нужно "слить" весь контент. Структура следующая : `http://lenfilm.tv/<число>`. Я написал всю логику парсера и в цикле парсю каждую страницу, включая внешние ссылки на загрузку файлов. Сливаю всю спарсенную информацию в текстовый файл в формате JSON. На сервере написал скрипт, который из файла раскидает информацию в таблицу в БД. Вот, вчера к ночи завел эту машину смерти и когда спарсилось 100 страниц я поставил все на стоп.

Вопрос именно **по тематике** сообщества, так как юристы не программисты))

## **Законен ли парсинг?**

Comment: В чем вопрос то?

Comment: @Tachkin, жирным, жирным

Comment: он законен, если одобрен владельцем сайта.

Comment: @KoVadim, кто-то разве одобряет?

Comment: А чем отличается получение информации с помощью парсера (поискового робота) от просмотра страницы? Просматривать законно?

Comment: Пишет "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable", наверное вы его положили своим трафиком )

Comment: @Tachkin, вы правы, ничем )

Comment: Не тематика Stack Overflow. Здесь не юридическая консультация.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian, :D сейчас )

Comment: Вам сюда https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AGS17 Не совсем согласен. Например, юристы могут меньше знать про законность cookies в России и практику применения, чем те, кто непосредственно имеет дело с сайтостроением.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он относится к юриспруденции, а не к программированию или системному администрированию.

Comment: Да, совершенно законен. Владелец сайта может запрещать это в условиях использования сайта и на этом основании блокировать вам доступ к сайту (банить). Но ничего более серьёзного. Серьёзности начнутся, если (а) ваша деятельность помешает нормальной работе сайта и повлечёт для владельцев доп. расходы на выч. ресурсы или недоступность для пользователей, (б) вы будете распространять полученные таким образом объекты авторского права с нарушениями условий. Возможно, и в других случаях. Правда, ситуация становится сложнее, когда речь об уязвимостях и персональных данных.

Comment: Как мне казалось это скрейпинг, а не парсинг...... так что встает вопрос почему парсинг может быть незаконным?)

Comment: @D-side, вся информация будет распростроняться и использоваться. Можно сказать, что сайт будет нашим донором, весь контент будет наш

Comment: @Flippy: Тогда я бы посоветовал обратиться к юристу, чтобы вам не оказаться крайним.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это абсолютно законно и никаким образом не нарушает никаких авторских прав. Только поставьте адекватную задержку между запросами иначе ваши действия могут подпасть под [ст. 272 УК РФ "Неправомерный доступ к компьютерной информации"](http://www.consultant.ru/cons/cgi/online.cgi?req=doc&base=LAW&n=215546&fld=134&dst=969,0&rnd=0.13502521455991223#0).

Comment: А если потом использовать эту информацию в своих целях?

Comment: @AGS17, именно это меня и интересует. А что за задержка? Секунды хватит?

Comment: @Flippy не более 30 обращений в минуту с одого IP адреса, согласано ст. 272 п. 4 уголовного кодекса РФ.

Comment: @Flippy зачастую вся информация, находящаяся на сайте, защищена авторским правом и запрещена для копирования без разрешения владельца. Но опять же, повторюсь: это не тематика раздела. Если вас интересует юриспруденция -> вам сюда https://law.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AGS17 ваша ссылка на английском

Comment: @Flippy Задержка должна быть такой чтобы вы не навредили сайту, сделав его недоступным.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian ваш троллинг тут не уместен - его могут воспринять серьезно.

Comment: @Khipster, ну думаю парсинг не равно dos атака.. Если у них сервак слабый то это их проблемы, разве нет? Ведь по сути парсинг это загрузка кода страницы и ее анализ. Или проще говоря, открывается страница.

Comment: Ну. Не важно. Пауза в секунду значит

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian, по поводу _не более 30 обращений в минуту с одого IP адреса, согласано ст. 272 п. 4 уголовного кодекса РФ_:  с ума сошли ))) Я сейчас посмотрел на стартовую страницу гугла у меня проходит 38 запросов за 0,4сек

Comment: @Tachkin ждите пативен

Comment: Слил контент, вроде не ищут ;)